# Devise & omniauth Facebook authentication in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I've followed [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) for getting Devise Facebook authentication to work and I've now come to a point where I can't understand and I would like some help.

I get the Sign in with Facebook link but clicking on it I get the following error, telling me there's something wrong with the routes

> Unknown action
>
> Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/auth/facebook". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end

Here is my routes file

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
  root :to => 'home#index'
```

Edit:

Solved that issue by changing the routes to

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Now I got the next error getting the Facebook auth to work but when coming back from the "Allow app screen" ruby throws...

> undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
>
> activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1060:in`request'
>   faraday (0.6.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:51:in `call'
>   faraday (0.6.1) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in`call'
>   faraday (0.6.1) lib/faraday/request.rb:88:in `run'
>   faraday (0.6.1) lib/faraday/request.rb:28:in`run'
>   faraday (0.6.1) lib/faraday/connection.rb:170:in `run_request'
>   oauth2 (0.4.1) lib/oauth2/client.rb:63:in`request'
>
> ...

This is using Rails 3.1.0rc8 and ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 2):

I just finished yesterday my omniauth login for my app, using exactly the same guide and rails 3.1 final

Not sure you did your routes ok, mine look like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
  get 'sign_in', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  get 'sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end

devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
```

In my `devise_for :users` block I put the sign in and sign out because I'm using OmniAuth without other authentications

The guide also sais that the `get '/users/auth/:provider'` line should be in a `devise_scope :user`

Not sure this will fix your problem, but at least I wanted to state out these points, which don't fit in a comment

Comment: I think you may answer my problem. I am also having similar issue in omniauth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561140/i-am-using-rails-cast-omniauth-and-i-get-this-error#