# Linked In authentication and aggregate data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm building a web app with Ruby on Rails and I want my users to authenticate and aggregate data from Linked In (and others like Github, Twitter, etc...).

I am using these gems:

- Devise for registration
- omniauth-linkedin for authentication
- pengwynn/linkedin for data aggregation

Though, Linked In has a not-so-nice pin thing.
Is there a way to avoid it and get the data I want from my users account without having them to go to linked in, fetch a pin and submit it to me?

Thanks in advance.

**authentications_controller.rb**

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
  end

  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.
          find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.
            create!(provider: omniauth['provider'], uid: omniauth['uid'])
      current_user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in(:user, user)
        redirect_to user_path(user.username)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: What is "not-so-nice" pin thing?

Comment: To get data and setup a LinkedIn::Client properly, you need a pin which linked in provides the user.